# Postgres Service Not start using via HomeBrew

Tags: postgresql, psql, mac-os-x, macos

I have to install homebrew in my macOS then after I tried to install Postgres on my mac using the homebrew. but when I checked my Postgres status is it not running.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

I have tried with that cmd but it only gives me pg_ctl: could not start server

```
2019-07-16 18:32:36.148 IST [9541] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-07-16 18:32:36.149 IST [9541] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-07-16 18:32:36.162 IST [9541] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
2019-07-16 18:32:36.166 IST [9542] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-07-14 17:27:00 IST
2019-07-16 18:32:36.350 IST [9542] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
2019-07-16 18:32:36.350 IST [9542] LOG:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
2019-07-16 18:32:36.350 IST [9542] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_replslot": No such file or directory
2019-07-16 18:32:36.350 IST [9541] LOG:  startup process (PID 9542) exited with exit code 1
2019-07-16 18:32:36.350 IST [9541] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2019-07-16 18:32:36.352 IST [9541] LOG:  database system is shut down
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I have tried find some solution but not working for me.

Comment: have you tried:  brew services start postgresql ?

Comment: By logs provided by you i think you have delete pg_tblspc and pg_replslot directory from data-diectory of postgresql 11.4 kindly put back those if you can't recover just create it using mkdir pg_tblspc with postgres user permission and start again

Comment: @Chessbrain I check that but not working for me